# Setting up structs and nodes for binary search in C, Memory violations

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, access-violation

I am trying to implement a binary search tree to look up morse code translations, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the concept, and the structs involved.

My more specific problem is that I'm getting some memory violation, like I'm writing to memory not available to me.

My structs look like this...

```
typedef struct mtn{
    char ASCII;
    int isinit;
    struct mtn *dah;
    struct mtn *dit;
} MTN;

typedef struct tree{
    struct mtn *root;
} Tree;
```

And the code in question is where I am trying to initialize the tree.

Specifically...

```
struct mtn* mtnNew()
{
    struct mtn *node;
    node = (MTN *)malloc(sizeof(MTN));
    node->isinit = 0;
    node->dit = NULL;
    node->dah = NULL;
    return node;
}

void initializeTree(char ch, char *mch, Tree *tr)
{
    MTN *curr = NULL;

    int i = 0;

    tr-> root = mtnNew();      //This is where the program breaks
```

And in case anyone has any tips, here's the rest of the function...

```
void initializeTree(char ch, char *mch, Tree *tr)
{
    MTN *curr = NULL;

    int i = 0;

    tr-> root = mtnNew();

    curr = tr-> root;

    if(strlen(mch) == 1)
    {
        if(mch[i] == '-')
        {
            curr = mtnNew();
            curr-> dah-> ASCII = ch;
            curr-> dah-> isinit++;
        }
        else if(mch[i] == '.')
        {
            curr = mtnNew();
            curr-> dit-> ASCII = ch;
            curr-> dit-> isinit++;
        }
        else
            printf("wut");
    }


    while(mch[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(mch[i] == '-')
        {
            if(curr-> dah == NULL)
                curr-> dah = mtnNew();
            curr = curr-> dah;
            i++;
        }
        else if(mch[i] == '.')
        {
            if(curr-> dit == NULL)
                curr-> dit = mtnNew();
            curr = curr-> dit;
            i++;
        }
    }

    curr-> ASCII = ch;
    curr-> isinit++;

    return;
}
```

Anyways, any help is appreciated, as is direction to good references or otherwise helpful information.

Thanks!

EDIT:

buff, buffs, and myTree are initialized as follows...

```
char buff, buffs[8];
Tree *myTree = NULL;
```

My call to initializeTree()

```
while(!feof(BTkeyFile))
{
    i = 0;
    buff = fgetc(BTkeyFile);
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        buffs[i] = '\0';
    while(buffs[--i] != '\n')
    {
        buffs[i] = fgetc(BTkeyFile);
        i++;
    }
    initializeTree(buff, buffs, myTree);
}
```

And the file it's reading from is in format

```
A.-
B-...
C-.-.
D-..
E.

etc.
```

EDIT 2:

It is definitely the line `tr-> root = mtnNew();` that breaks the code, inside of the function and in main() the error stops on that line.

Comment: How do you call `initializeTree()`?

Comment: I added an edit showing how it's done @Rohan

Comment: `curr = mtnNew();` Association is lost.

Comment: I was hoping you add more details about call the parameters, how they are defined, initialized etc. But unfortunately that is not in your added code. BTw have you tried using `gdb` or other debugger?

Comment: I added a little more information. I'm writing in visual studio and have been using their debugger. @Rohan  Also I tried the suggested `curr = mtnNew();` and it seems to be stuck in some loop... But with no error message. @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Tree *myTree = NULL;
```

means that you're dereferencing `((Tree*)NULL)->root` inside your function. Dereferencing `NULL` is bad. Try this instead:

```
Tree myTree;
initializeTree(buff, buffs, &myTree);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are passing `myTree` which is `NULL` to `initializeTree()`. You are referencing it as `tr->root = mtnNew()` which would give you crash as `tr` is `NULL`.

You should allocate memory to `myTree` before passing it to the initialize function.

Something like:

```
Tree *myTree = malloc(sizeof(*myTree));
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're suggesting.. should I malloc memory of size `struct mtn` before passing it to the function, and then set it equal to `mtnNew()` in the function as well?